# Как заменить букву в словаре?

Tags: python

Возможно ли заменить все буквы на заглавные?

```
dictionary = {'Jane': "24",
      'klMike': '67'
      }
```

Comment: так преобразовать `JANE`, `KIMIKE`?

Comment: Да, если возможно, то как

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [словарное включение](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) для перебора элементов и метод строки [upper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) для преобразование ключей к верхнему регистру:

```
dictionary = {k.upper():v for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: from funcy import walk_keys # pip install funcy

In [2]: dictionary = {'Jane': "24",
   ...:       'klMike': '67'
   ...:       }
   ...:

In [3]: walk_keys(str.upper, dictionary)
Out[3]: {'JANE': '24', 'KLMIKE': '67'}
```